# How to escape wildcard characters in "like" clause?

Tags: hibernate, hql, wildcard

How can I escape the wildcard characters in a like clause?

E.g.:

```
select foo from Foo as foo where foo.bar like '%' || :filter ||'%'
```

```
query.setParameter("filter", "%");
query.list(); 
// I'd expect to get the foo's containing the '%' in bar, not all of them!
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Hibernate 3 you can use the escape parameter to specify the escape char:

```
select foo from Foo as foo where foo.bar like '!%' escape '!'
```

I think that should work, although I have never tried it in practice.

Comment: @DeanPovey Didn't work with mine: `Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: escape near line 1, column 175 [select e.id,e.title,e.type.icon,e.typeObject,e.idDomain from package.SomeClass e where ( UPPER(e.title) LIKE ?) AND e.idDomain =? escape '!' ]`