# How to use Hibernate Analyzer?

Tags: hibernate, lucene, escaping, character, hibernate-search

I am trying to search for special characters in my hibernate query, I use QueryParser.escape(String searchTerm) to put a '\' character in front of all the special characters to escape them properly.

However I have found out that the standard analyzer used to tokenize removes these special characters from the index, so even if you properly escape the term 'abc-def' if you try and search it you would have to search 'abc def'.

So what analyzer should I use/how should I specify for the analyzer not to remove the special character when indexing?

A snippet of my annotated class and query building below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="jobReq")
@Indexed
public class JobReq {

@Id
@DocumentId
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Field
@Column(name="jobId", nullable=false, unique=true)
private String jobId;

@Fields({@Field, @Field(name = "jobIdSort", analyze = Analyze.NO)})
@Column(name="jobIdSort", nullable=false, unique=true)
private String jobIdSort;

@Field
@Column(name="jobTitle", nullable=false)
private String jobTitle;
```

Query:

```
tempQ = (org.apache.lucene.search.Query) qb.keyword()
                                .wildcard()
                                .onField(allFields[i].getName().toString())
                                .matching(QueryParser.escape(termToFind) + "*")
                                .createQuery();
                    }   
                    bq.add(new BooleanClause(tempQ, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD));
                }
            }
        }
        //wrap Lucene query in an org.hibernate.Query
        hibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(bq, this.type).setSort(sort);
        results = hibQuery.list();
        System.out.println(bq);
        fullTextSession.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Have you seen some of the other similar questions like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006524/how-to-escape-wildcard-characters-in-like-clause-in-hql

Comment: I am using the escape characters by calling the QueryParser.escape() it escapes the query properly, but the way the data is tokenized in the DB removes the special character from the index so it isn't searchable.  I tried using the KeywordAnalyzer `@Analyzer(impl = KeywordAnalyzer.class)
    @Field()
 @Column(name="jobId", nullable=false, unique=true)
 private String jobId;`  But it doesn't return anything in my search.  Also I'm not building the query 'by hand' with strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I don't believe it makes any sense to use `QueryParser.escape`.  That is designed to escape a string-form query in preparation for parsing.  You aren't using a `QueryParser`, and have stated in comments you don't intend to.  You mention that you tried keyword analyzer already.  I suspect the problem there is that you *were* running it through the `QueryParser.escape` method, and it was adding an, in that context, extraneous backslash, preventing matches being found.

---

If you were inclined to use QueryParser instead, and utilize analysis, you might create something like this:

```
SearchFactory searchFactory = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory();
org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(defaultField, searchFactory.getAnalyzer(JobReq.class) );
/* 
 create your BooleanQuery, loop, whatever else
*/
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = parser.parse( allFields[i].getName().toString() + ":" + QueryParser.escape(termToFind) + "*" );
    bq.add(new BooleanClause(tempQ, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD));

hibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(bq).setSort(sort);
results = hibQuery.list();
```

Comment: I tried this using the `KeywordAnalyzer` and not specifying an analyzer (I think it uses scopeAnalyzer?) in the annotated class and also tried different combinations with that in the `QueryParser` and it still wouldn't return a result with the format 'abc-def'

Comment: Yes, also tried it without escaping. Its like the value isn't even indexed, as when I just do a plain search for 'ab*' for the term 'abc-def' that also doesn't show up whereas when I first started and had just a basic search query I could search for 'abc*' or even 'abc def' (space replaces the special char) and it would show up

Comment: That `ab*` generates no hits does seem odd.  Have you looked at the final boolean query generated (`Query.toString()`) to make sure it looks like you expect?

Comment: Yes it seems correct: `jobId:nou-335573 jobTitle:nou-335573 contract:nou-335573 project:nou-335573 laborCategory:nou-335573 summary:nou-335573 jobDescription:nou-335573 status:nou-335573 TTONumber:nou-335573 TTONumber:nou-335573 TTONumber:nou-335573 requiredSkills:nou-335573 jobId:nou-335573` is what I have currently with the field 'jobId' set with the keyword analyzer and not escaped, though when it is escaped properly I looked at it and it did have the `\` inserted where they should have been.  I have a feeling its something with the index not being set properly.

Comment: Omg I just got it to work, with the query string  (jobId:nwb jobId:528864), I guess the parenthesis are important. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Or rather, just not searching for the special characters lol, which shouldn't be an issue in this application.

NOTE: I am using the default 'scopeanalyzer' and parser