# How to escape colon in HQL?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a condition part of my query as follows:

```
...
where foo.bar like '%:%'
```

The query would execute but with no result. I think it's because of the colon since it is a reserved char in HQL. So how can I escape it without sending the `:` as a parameter to my query?

I have already used `'%\:%'` and `'%\\\\:%'` with no success.

Comment: Try this [:] peraphs depends by DBMS

Comment: Show this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006524/how-to-escape-wildcard-characters-in-like-clause-in-hql

Comment: Are you sure you have a `foo.bar` containing a `:` in your table? I would expect this query to execute fine and it seems it does. If there was a problem with this character, it woul dprobably throw an exception instead of running. Turn SQL logging on and see what SQL query is being executed.

Comment: bar is actually the subject of an email. assume the subject is "FWD: test", if I put 'FWD' or 'test' between %s I will have the result but with colon there will be no output.

Comment: I found a solution: q=q.replaceAll(":","'||unistr('\\\\003A')||'");

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
q=q.replaceAll(":","'||unistr('\\\\003A')||'");
```