# Hibernate convert Date Format to Question Mark

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I am creating a sql query through hibernate. I have a select query like;

```
SELECT IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(q.create_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'), ' ') as createDate ..
```

but hibernate converts that query to

```
SELECT IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(q.create_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H?'), ' ') as createDate
```

So it thinks that i need to send a parameter for question mark.

Is there any idea why this is happening ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the `:` in Hibernate.

Refer to this post - [Using Hibernate query : colon gets treated as parameter / escaping colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475876/using-hibernate-query-colon-gets-treated-as-parameter-escaping-colon)

You can do it by changing the query to:

```
SELECT IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(q.create_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H\\:%i'), ' ') as createDate ..
```

**Update:**

Alternatively, you can replace with unicode character as mentioned in this post - [how to escape colon in HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614960/how-to-escape-colon-in-hql)

q=q.replaceAll(":","'||unistr('\\003A')||'");

Comment: In that case, hibernate converts it as `'%Y-%m-%d %H\:%i'` and returns an error says **'Not all named parameters have been set: [%i]'**

Comment: This doesn't work either. It completely changes the colon with that string (`'%Y-%m-%d %H'||unistr('003A')||'%i'`) On the link provided, HQL is used. I am using SQL. That might be the problem.